# Error when setting text in an EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an editText element in Android and when I want to set the text (after a buttom is pressed), I get the following error:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID
> #0x2

So here is the problematic part of my Java code:

```
 if(view.getId()==R.id.addBtn) { // A buttom is pressed
            int quantity=  Integer.parseInt(binding.itemEditText.getText().toString()); //Read the current value of the EditText Element
            if(quantity<100) {
                quantity++; //Increase the value by 1
                binding.itemEditText.setText(quantity); //Set the value of the EditText element
            }
        }
```

Here is the XML code of the edit text

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/itemEditText"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:minEms="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            />
```

Does anyone know why this problem occurs? I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: What is `R.id.addBtn` and are you sure that this error is related to `itemEditText` and not `R.id.addBtn`? Also, if you want to make sure that the operation is done once the button is clicked, instead of using `if` statement, simply use `button.setOnClickListener`

Comment: just be sure the "itemEditText" is bonded the correct layout. You can also try traditional format without view binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace it

```
binding.itemEditText.setText(quantity);
```

to

```
binding.itemEditText.setText(quantity+"");
```

because method setText has two variants: with String parameter and int parameter. Last variant is string resourse ID

Comment: Thanks a lot Ann Developer for your answer. Now everything is okay. I appreciate your help and I accpeted and upvoted your answer.

Comment: I'd use `quantity.toString()` instead of implicit transformation

Comment: Thanks Ilya for your comment. quantity does not have a toString() method